# Bellman equation / dynamic programming for darts

Tags: optimization, reinforcement-learning, dynamic-programming, value-iteration

When you play darts, you can throw at 62 regions, ***z*** on the dartboard. Namely, the singles regions *S1, ..., S20,* the double regions *D1, ..., D20*, the treble regions *T2, ..., T20* and the single- and double bullseye, *SB and DB.*
Every region has a numerical score, ***h***. Lets say, that ***mu*** represents the location on the dartboard where the player aims at. In addition, we know the probability of hitting any ***z*** when aiming for ***mu***.

Ignoring turns, a player wants to minimize the expected number of throws to get to zero. This can be formulated as a stochastic shortest path DP. The state space for this DP is *s {1, 2, ..., 501}* and represents the players score. *i* denotes the number of darts thrown. The goal is to determine the aiming location that minimizes the expected number of throws.

When a player throws, there are three possible outcomes:

- new score
- checkout
- bust

This can be formulated as:

[image]

In addition, we have a Bellman equation that satisfies

[image]

The terminal condition is equal to

```
V(0)=0
```

We can solve the DP successively for ***s*** *= 2, ..., 501*. All of the above can be found on page 13 of the following [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/346143239_Play_Like_the_Pros_Solving_the_Game_of_Darts_as_a_Dynamic_Zero-Sum_Game).

Just for my understanding, please let me know if I understand the methodology correctly:
If we have ***s**=2*, there is only one legal action, *D1*. This the only *p(z; mu)* we consider, correct? Because other possibilities of ***z*** results in busts. And then you have basically a circular reference where the value of *V(2)* is

```
V(f(2,0) = V(2)
```

In addition, throwing *D1* when aiming for ***mu*** gives the terminal condition

```
V(f(2, D1)) = 0
```

So, the Bellman equation will always be equal 1 correct? Although, the probability of throwing *D1* is larger when the player aims for *D1* than for *DB*, the product of the probabilities and the terminal condition is always 0. So, it doesn't matter where you aim on the dartboard, but this feels incorrect.

Please advice!

Comment: No, because at each stage you are *adding* 1 to the summation term, and this carries backwards; after going backwards $N$ stages, you would have added 1 $N$ times.

Comment: I specified that I meant for s = 2

Comment: The averaging over $p(z;u)$ converts the overall calculation to be, in effect, 1 + the expected number of stages remaining until termination.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your point. In the first stage, where S=2, where should the player aim at? Could be anywhere right? Because every `p(2;u)` is multiplied by `V(0)=0`. Or am I seeing this wrong?